# converting string date into format yyyy-MM-dd to pass in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting the date in form of string to which i convert into below format 
yyyy-MM-dd and finally the object should be of date type so that later I want
it to be added in hibernate criteria ..

```
public List<abc> eee(Long tradeId,
            String sfsdf, boolean dfds,
             String SettlementDate,
            ) {


query.add(Restrictions.eq("abcDate", <whatever date I am getting in yyyy-MM-dd>);
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is a Date in the DB then you need to have the Object as a `Date`.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
String myDate = "20-03-2014";
Date date = formatter.parse(myDate);

query.add(Restrictions.eq("abcDate", date));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 String YourDate = "2014-03-20 03:30:12"
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
 Date ConDate = dateFormat.parse(YourDate);
```

Comment: There is no need to initialize `ConDate` with a constructor. By the way why such a coding convention?